# Multiple LaTeX installations

Tags: installing, texmaker, versions

The first time I installed LaTeX was in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive` (~600MB).
Yesterday I installed TeX Live from apt-get, I simply don't know where it has been installed (~1GB).
Today I installed Tex Live from [tug.org](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) (~4.5GB). It's in `/usr/local/texlive/2013`.
However both Kyle and TeXMaker are still using the first installation.

How can I choose which version to use?

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

My solution in TexMaker was to go to Options->Configure Texmaker and add the desired path to pdflatex: `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`.

However I think it would be better to have the possibility of changing the global path to bin.